# Modify html before submitting form: prevent this hack

Tags: php, html, forms, security

I came to a realization that malicious users can modify the html of a form in their browser before submitting a form.
For example, switching the names of two input fields of the same types.

I am creating a website that's largely dependent upon relationships between each entries in the database.

If this happens, it could jeopardize all functions of my sites. (I've tested it, and it does switched the inputs from the two fields who names are switched in the browser by the user, ie. me)

How could we prevent this?

Answer (score 8):

If this kind of hack causes problem on the server side, you cannot fix it in your browser code. It means that you need to fix this on the server.

Anyone can generate any kind of POST or GET to your server, and you need to be prepared for that.

So, make sure that you detect this kind of tampering on the server, and deal with it there, by returning an error message, or by silently ignoring such invalid requests.

If the server is prepared for this, you can let people hack away in their browser as much as they want.

Comment: In my particular situation, my DB accept two  text fields among others. Both have similar characteristics, so can't validate based on the type.  The entries in the DB have real world meaning relationships to one and other depending on these two fields. Could you be more specific as how "make sure that you detect this kind of tampering.."

Comment: @William Sham: Just some sanity checks. Are values of the expected length? If you're expecting a number, is this a number? Is the value in the expected range? Does the combination of posted variables make sense? Is the current user allowed to retrieve the requested information? These kinds of sanity checks cannot be generalized. You need to think about this every time you deal with a posted variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should be validating your inputs as seen on the [PHP Manual for Validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php). For example, we have form inputs `title` and `body` for a post. When the user submits the post, the `title` should be between 1 to 40 characters, so we should validate that through PHP. Second, the `body` should not contain malicious text or code, so we should sanitize that with a function such as `addslahes()`.

The entire topic revolves around PHP security. The only way to prevent hacking attempts and malicious intent is to learn security. Start learning with the link above.

Comment: `addslashes` does not help much on anything.

Comment: Just an example. I can't cover the entire breadth of PHP security in a single answer.

Comment: You don't have to. I just said `addslashes` is a bad example, because it just gives you a false sense of security.

Comment: I am aware of validating based on type and some technique to prevent malicious code.
But what if the users literally switch the name of two fields of the same validation type and submit the form

Comment: @user76300 You can't do anything about what a user does on the client side. You can't tell their browser that it'll break your server-side code. If a user intentionally switches the name of two fields, they usually have malicious intent anyway; thus, your options are two prevent submission of the form completely or use server-side validation to prevent critical damage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the simplest and often best solution is to check if each input field has a valid value with php before sending the query to the DB. For example, a field with the name "telephone" should only be numeric and not longer then say 10 ciphers. Make the rules strict enough and you shouldn't have any problems. In addition you should also make sure your DB fields are strict ie. only allow the length and data type you want.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, both fields are similar types. Thanks anyway